# Proving that complex function is a zero function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let's consider holomorphic function
$$f:\Delta (0, 1) \rightarrow \mathbb C$$

such that $$\limsup_{|z|\rightarrow 1}\frac{|f(z)|}{1 - |z|} < \infty$$

where $\Delta(z_0, r) = \{z \in \mathbb C: |z - z_0| < r\}$

I want to prove that $f \equiv0$.

I have little troubles with this exercise. I tried to use identity rule i.e. there is a theorem which says that when we consider $$Z(f):=\{z \in \Delta(0, 1):f(z) = 0\}$$ consisting of limit point then $f \equiv 0$. However, I'm not sure how to prove that this set consist limit point using fact that $\limsup_{|z|\rightarrow 1}\frac{|f(z)|}{1 - |z|} < \infty$. Can I ask you for a hand in solving this problem? Is there any other approach to this problem?

Comment: +1 for a good question

Answer (score 3):

The condition $$\limsup_{|z|\to 1^{-}}\frac{|f(z)|}{1 - |z|} < \infty$$
gives  $$\lim_{r\to 1^-}\max_{|z|=r} |f(z)| =0.$$ Assume $|f(z_0)|>0$ for a point $|z_0|<1.$ There exists $r,$ such that $|z_0|<r<1 $ and $$\max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|<|f(z_0)|.$$  On the other hand, by the maximum modulus principle, we get $$\max_{|z|=r} |f(z)| \ge |f(z_0)|.$$ This gives a contradiction.